# How to get TopicID message was sent to in supergroup converted to forum?

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I am trying to parse message sent to topic in forum group, by cannot find in Message class TopicID. PeerID is parent group id, version of library 3.5.3

(https://core.telegram.org/api/forum)

Does library supports supergroups converted to forum? Any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

the topic ID of a message can be found in:

```cs
(message.reply_to as MessageReplyHeader)?.reply_to_top_id
or
(message.reply_to as MessageReplyHeader)?.reply_to_msg_id (if above is 0)
```

Comment: `"reply_to": {
                    "flags": 8,
                    "reply_to_msg_id": 2,
                    "reply_to_peer_id": null,
                    "reply_to_top_id": 0
                }` - this message from topic but without reply_to_top_id, real topic id is reply_to_msg_id.

any way to get all topics for channel?

Comment: if it's a direct msg in a topic, it will be in reply_to_msg_id
but if it's a reply to another msg in the same topic, then it will be in reply_to_top_id

Comment: get all topics: https://corefork.telegram.org/method/channels.getForumTopics

Comment: the question is: how to get forum topics using wtelegramclient ?

Comment: @Kolka I can show you the way to do it if you publish a question. I've been writing an helper class based on WTelegramClient API to do lots of helpful things, like a universal function to retrieve all topics from a channel/group.